# Avoid string "null" using split method of javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I am trying to parse a string with a following format

```
"value1=name1:value2=test1,value1=name2:value2=null,value1=null:value2=test3"
```

I would want this to be parsed as

```
[{ value1: "name1", value2: "test1"}, { value1: "name2", value2: "NA"},{ value1: "NA", value2: "test3"}]
```

If in case any value post splititng is null , just make is "NA". Since I am using `split` the null value is being coerced to string. Hence setting "NA" using `nullish coalescing(??)` is not working and hence it still returns null and not NA. It would also be helpful , If any body can suggest a simpler way to achieve this

Code that I have tried.

```
let input = "value1=name1:value2=test1,value1=name2:value2=null,value1=null:value2=test3";
let items = input.split(",");
let pairs = items.map((item) => {
  let splitItems = item.split(":");
  let value1 = splitItems[0].split("=")?? "NA";;
  let value2 = splitItems[1].split("=") ?? "NA";
  return { value1, value2 };
});
```

Comment: You can filter out matches containing null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the ternary operator

```js
const str =
  "value1=name1:value2=test1,value1=name2:value2=test2,value1=null:value2=test3"

const res = str.split(",").map((el) =>
  el.split(":").reduce((acc, pair) => {
    const [key, value = "NA"] = pair.split("=")
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: value === "null" ? "NA" : value,
    }
  }, {})
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: In case I want it to be parsed as { "SomeVal": "name1", "SomeVal2": "test1"}. rather than taking keys from input, I want a different one in the result?

Comment: @li97 then you could change the property as you want, like `{ [buildKey(key)]: ... }` and custom your expected key with the key taken from input

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this:

```
(string || '').split("=") || "NA";
```

Comment: Step 1. We replace null with empty string step2. We chose splitted strinh or na

Answer (score 0):

maybe that is not a simpler but easy and saver way to parse your string, and it is versatile enough to provide key value pairs as many where provided

```js
const input = "value1=name1:value2=test1:value3=name3:value4=test4,value1=name2:value2=test2,value1=null:value2=test3";

const mappedKey = {
  value3: 'someNewKey1',
  value4: 'someNewKey2',
};

const parseData = (input) => {

  // replace directly all null values before splitting
  const stream = input.replace(/null/g, 'NA');

  // now split by comma and equal sign
  const parsedStream = stream.split(",").map((fragment) => {

    // build a key value object, to be able to collect n value pairs
    const obj = {};

    // split groups by -> :
    const values = fragment.split(':').map((split) => {

      // split key value pairs by -> =
      return split.split('=');
    });

    // collect the key value pais into obj
    values.forEach((data) => {
      const [key, value] = data;
      obj[mappedKey[key] || key] = value;
    });

    // return the final result
    return obj;
  });
 
  return parsedStream;
}

window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('.input').innerHTML = input;
  document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(parseData(input), null, 2);
}
```

```html
<h3>Input:</h3>
<pre class="input"></pre>
<hr />
<h3>Parsed result:</h3>
<pre class="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Object.fromentries since your split shows two values in the format [],[].

```js
let input = "value1=name1:value2=test1,value1=name2:value2=test2,value1=null:value2=test3";
let items = input.replace(/null/g, 'NA').split(",");
let pairs = items.map((item) => {
  let splitItems = item.split(":");
  let value5 = splitItems[0].split("=");
  let value6 = splitItems[1].split("=");
  return  Object.fromEntries([value5,value6])
});

console.log(pairs)
```